# Copy specific region of bitmapdata object to another bitmapdata using copypixels() in action script

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am developing an online tool which edits images but I have a problem.  In copy specific region of bitmap to another bitmap.  What is the problem, can anyone help me out?

```
function enablepaste(event:MouseEvent)
{


tempShape.graphics.clear();
mv_temp.graphics.clear();
var rect = new Rectangle(tempstartX,tempstartY,endX,endY);
var pnt =new Point(tempstartX,tempstartY);

tempBMP_data=new BitmapData(rect.width,rect.height,false,0);

tempBMP_data.copyPixels(stageBMP.bitmapData,rect,pnt , null, null, true );

   //tempBMP_data is destinagtion bitmap data object

tempBMP= new Bitmap(tempBMP_data);


mv_temp.addChild(tempBMP);



Paste_button.visible=true;
}
```

The problem that I am facing is that it shows only rectangle without copying graphics.

Answer (score 0):

I see there are two potential flaws:

1. When you perform copyPixels, shouldn't the destination point (3rd parameter) be Point(0,0)?
2. If the above adjustment does not yield correct result, I would consider clone the stageBMP, and move the clone a few pixels in both x and y direction, that way you can make sure that stageBMP is properly generated.

Comment: thanks for answer but with clone whole bitmap will be copied and i want specific area selected by the user

Comment: Oh, cloning the whole bitmap is not my suggested solution, I just said you could use that to confirm that stageBMP is properly generated.  Because if stageBMP is empty or black for some reason, you would get the result as your described in your question.

Comment: no.. image is already loaded into the stageBMP and working properly with other functionalities but only copy and paste is not working is there any other methods i can use????